# Как по команде временно приостановить все функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, disnake

Нужно создать команду для приостановки на время(которое бы задавалось), во время приостановки не должна работать ни одна команда, будь то event on_message, on_member_join или просто слэш-команды

```
global flag
flag = True

@bot.slash_command(name='off')
@bot.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def off(ctx):
    flag = False


@bot.slash_command(name='on')
@bot.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def on(ctx):
    flag = True
```

сделал через флаги просто, но выдает ошибку в has_permissions, как проверить использующего на администратора?

Comment: В начале каждой команды поставь проверку if not flag: return. flag меняй когда нужно вкл или выкл бота

Comment: спасибо, но теперь вопрос в проверке на администратора, сможете помочь?)

Comment: В бд создать нужно список админов. Если id в списке админов, то пропускаешь. Проверка наподобие if message.from_user.id in admin_list: ...

Comment: и снова благодарю) Все сделал, вопросы отпали